# Как найти точку пересечения ScrollViewer и Canvas?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-canvas

Пытаюсь сделать контрол на основе `Canvas` / `Panel`, который будет отображать элементы / рисовать в методе `OnRender` только те, что попадают в видимую область +/-. Такая виртуализация...

Элементы эти имеют координату верхней левой точки и размеры. Чтобы их отобразить, нужно отсеять лишние из общей коллекции. Для этого мне нужны размеры видимой области и точка пересечения `Canvas` и `ScrollViewer`.

С первым проблем нет. А вот найти точку пересечения не получается. Как это сделать? (Картинка для наглядности)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Закрашенная красная область - видимая область условного `Canvas` в `ScrollViewer`. Красная граница - доступная для прокрутки область, которую "вычисляю" в `MeasureOverride`.

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <controls:MarkMapperVirtualized Map="{Binding Map}"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

`MarkMapperVirtualized` производный от `Canvas`. В нем и хочу ловить эту точку, вероятно, реализуя `IScrollInfo` или еще как-нибудь.

Comment: А можно ваше дерево элементов? У вас ScrollViewer вложен в Canvas, а внутренние элементы вложены в ScrollViewer? Или как-то ещё?

Comment: @VladD, обновил вопрос. Canvas находится внутри ScrollViewer, естественно. Его прокручиваю и им же рисую в OnRender или же через добавление Child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня работает такой код:

```
ScrollViewer scrollViewer = ...;
Canvas canvas = (Canvas)scrollViewer.Content;

var viewportTopLeft = new Point(0, 0);
var viewportBottomRight = new Point(scrollViewer.ViewportWidth, scrollViewer.ViewportHeight);

foreach (UIElement child in canvas.Children)
{
    // вычисляем координаты относительно ScrollViewer'а.
    var childTopLeft = child.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), scrollViewer);
    var childBottomRight = new Point(childTopLeft.X + child.RenderSize.Width,
                                     childTopLeft.Y + child.RenderSize.Height);
    bool childIsVisible = RectsIntersect(
            viewportTopLeft, viewportBottomRight,
            childTopLeft, childBottomRight);
    // тут childIsVisible показывает, видна ли какая-нибудь часть child'а
}
```

Вспомогательные функции:

```
bool RectsIntersect(
    Point topleft1, Point bottomright1, Point topleft2, Point bottomright2)
{
    return SegmentsIntersect(topleft1.X, bottomright1.X, topleft2.X, bottomright2.X) &&
           SegmentsIntersect(topleft1.Y, bottomright1.Y, topleft2.Y, bottomright2.Y);
}

bool SegmentsIntersect(double l1, double r1, double l2, double r2)
{
    var left = Math.Max(l1, l2);
    var right = Math.Min(r1, r2);
    return left <= right;
}
```

Comment: RenderSize у Child почему-то не вычисляется. Он у меня сделан классом производным от `UIElement` только с одним `VisualChild`.

Comment: @Salnik: Странно, почему не вычисляется? У меня в примере работало. Дайте тогда воспроизводящий проблему код.

Comment: поместил `Canvas`'ы с хостами в еще один `Canvas`, теперь работает. Только в методе `TranslatePoint` нужно местами поменять `child` и `scrollViewer`, иначе выдает отрицательные значения, т.е. смещение, чтобы не пришлось инвертировать дополнительно.

Comment: Хм, странно, у меня работало и без этого. Ну хорошо, важно, что работает.